# SP2016 Content Enrichment service error cmdlets Set-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, enterprise-search, 2016

Team,

I am trying to implement How to: Use the Content Enrichment web service callout for SharePoint Server from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163982.aspx

But everything else seems to be fine, and when executing the powershell cmdlets

> Set-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration –SearchApplication $ssa –ContentEnrichmentConfiguration $config

I am getting the below error

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.SearchServiceApplicationPipeBind' 
>   required by parameter 'SearchApplication'. Specified method is not supported.

Please advise if I am missing anything obvious here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this error.

In my application there were two search services running.

So when used cmdlet

> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

it returned both services. I had to use the identity to select the services where i have to run this.

> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity "ServiceName"

so that helped resolve the issue and

now when i use the cmdlet

> Set-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration –SearchApplication $ssa –ContentEnrichmentConfiguration $config

It worked perfectly without any error.